# Unittest mock: return function which receives one pytest fixture and one argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I'm creating some unit tests and using pytest fixtures in combination with some unittest.mock `patch.object` calls.

I would like to reuse a function that is called by some of my tests. It makes use of a pytest fixture (specified as the first "argument" of the function) and it requires an additional argument. It looks something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytest
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.fixture()
def rootdir():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def my_mock_ret(rootdir, number):
    print(f"{rootdir}_{number}")
    return f"{rootdir}_{number}"

def test_simple(rootdir):
    a = pd.DataFrame()
    with patch.object(a, 'to_csv', lambda x: my_mock_ret(rootdir, x)) as _:
        a.to_csv(rootdir)
```

The tricky part is how to pass the `number` argument to `my_mock_ret` while also being able to access the `rootdir` fixture from inside it.

I've tried this way using lambda but it does not work.

#### Edit

It works if y put `my_mock_ret` inside `test_simple`, but I don't want to do that because I want to reuse `my_mock_ret` for several other tests:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytest
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.fixture()
def rootdir():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def test_simple(rootdir):
    def my_mock_ret(number):
        print(f"{rootdir}_{number}")
        return f"{rootdir}_{number}"

    a = pd.DataFrame()
    with patch.object(a, 'to_csv', my_mock_ret) as _:
        a.to_csv(rootdir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need right here, is the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytest
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.fixture()
def rootdir():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@pytest.fixture()
def my_mock_ret(rootdir):
    def _my_mock_ret(number):
        print(f"{rootdir}_{number}")
        return f"{rootdir}_{number}"
    return _my_mock_ret

def test_simple(my_mock_ret, rootdir):
    a = pd.DataFrame()
    with patch.object(a, 'to_csv', my_mock_ret) as _:
        a.to_csv(rootdir)
```

here `my_mock_ret` will create a function, which captures `rootdir`, and can take the `number` argument.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had also found another solution, basically keeping `my_mock_ret` as a normal function and changing the `rootdir` argument name (`my_rootdir`). Then, the lambda solution from my original post works. @tituszban is there any advantage to your solution vs mine?

Comment: Only on a conceptual level, as this allows you to have other fixture dependencies in your my_mock_ret, without the test needing those dependencies as well.